# How to find a list element

Tags: python-2.7

I have this list

```
['{"activities":[{"activity":"111","interface":"eds","clientIp":"12.207.212.130","logTime":1469811993000},{"activity":"121","dbCount":33,"totalHits":24,"query":"TI', 'the', 'plague","searchedFrom":"Unknown","searchType":"And","logTime":1469811994000}],"session":-2147479722,"customerId":"s8905647","groupId":"main","profileId":"eds"}']
```

and I want to write this whole list as is in a file only if `"activity":"121"` is present in this list only after occurrence of `"activity":"111"`. Like in this example, 1st `"activity":"111"` is present and later `"activity":"121"` is also present and I would like this list to be written in file and any list where `"activity":"121"` is NOT followed anywhere after `"activity":"111"`, that I don't want to write.

How do I do this ? Please help.

Comment: Do you mean for this list to be a one element list with a string that looks like a dictionary?  Or is it supposed to be a list of dictionaries?

Comment: You should probably just use `json.loads()` on your string. This will return a dictionary that will be easier and more efficient to work with.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is based on the assumption that you are trying to search through a list of dictionaries, so I've corrected the list as such. You'll also get errors if a dictionary in your list doesn't contain the key you're searching for. For that purpose I've added simple error handling to the function.

I am a Python novice, so there could exist a more elegant solution than mine, but it may be enough for what you need. It works like this: if an occurrence of key 'activity' with the value '111' is found, the rest of the list is searched for the occurrence of key 'activity' with the 'value 121'. Simple enough.

If, however, you only consider the conditions met if activity 121 is found in the very next dictionary after the occurrence of activity 111, you can simply change line 14 to this:

```
if i[key] == valueTwo and foundOne and (dictCount - 1) == countHelp:
```

Also, I'm not sure if you are trying to write the dictionary where activity 121 was found first after activity 111, or if you want to write the entire list of dictionaries. Variable 'myDictionaries' is the whole list, variable 'i' is just the first dictionary where activity 121 was found after activity 111.

You will be writing from line 16, which in my solution just prints out the list without writing to file. So just change it to your file writing solution.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function # You can remove this line if you're using Python 3.

def searchDictionaries(key, valueOne, valueTwo, myDictionaries): # Define the function with four arguments
    dictCount = 0 # Initialize the count of dictionaries in the list
    foundOne = False # Initialize the state for meeting the first condition
    countHelp = 0 # This will help us determine if the second condition is met in the dictionary right after the first condition was met
    for i in myDictionaries: # Start looping through the list of dictionaries
        dictCount = dictCount + 1 # Increase count at every iteration
        try:
            if i[key] == valueOne: # Check if the first condition is met (if the value of activity is 111)
                foundOne = True # Change the state of meeting the first condition to True
                countHelp = dictCount # Keep this in case you want to modify the next line to only search in the next dictionary
            if i[key] == valueTwo and foundOne: # Check if the second condition (activity value of 121) is present in any subsequent dictionary
                # If you made it here, both conditions were met and you can write to file
                print(myDictionaries) # Write the whole list of dictionaries to file. Use print(i) if you want to just print the first dictionary where you found 121 after 111 was found.
                break # Stop searching
        except Exception as e: # Error handling
            print('Warning: %s - There is no key %s in dictionary %s.' % (e, e, dictCount))

    return

# Your example list of dictionaries
myListOfDicts = [
{'activity': '111', 'interface': 'eds', 'clientIp': '12.207.212.130', 'logTime': 1469811993000},
{'session': -2147479722, 'dbCount': 33, 'totalHits': 24, 'query': 'TI', 'the': 'plague', 'searchedFrom': 'Unknown', 'searchType': 'And', 'logTime': 1469811994000},
{'activity': '121', 'customerId': 's8905647', 'groupId': 'main', 'profileId': 'eds'}
]

# Now you can call the function searchDictionaries with your desired values > key, first value, second value, name of your list of dictionaries
searchDictionaries('activity', '111', '121', myListOfDicts)
```

I hope others can help you with any subsequent questions, as I  don't have enough points to use the Comment feature.

Answer (score 0):

As another answer I'm adding a solution based on the assumption your list is one element with a string, in which case your originally posted list needs no correction.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Your example list
myListOfDicts = ['{"activities":[{"activity":"111","interface":"eds","clientIp":"12.207.212.130","logTime":1469811993000},{"activity":"121","dbCount":33,"totalHits":24,"query":"TI', 'the', 'plague","searchedFrom":"Unknown","searchType":"And","logTime":1469811994000}],"session":-2147479722,"customerId":"s8905647","groupId":"main","activity":"111"}']

sanitizedList = str(myListOfDicts).replace('"', '') # Convert the list to string and emove double-quotes for simpler search

activityOne = 'activity:111,' # Set the search pattern for string 1
activityTwo = 'activity:121,' # Set the search pattern for string 2
foundFirst = False # Initialize status of whether the first string was found

search111 = sanitizedList.find(activityOne) # Check position of activity 111
search121 = sanitizedList.find(activityTwo) # Check position of activity 121

# Set status of foundFirst to True if activity 111 was found
if search111 > 0:
    foundFirst = True

# If activity 111 was found before activity 121, you can print
if foundFirst and search111 < search121:
    print 'Now you can write to file'
```

I'm curious as to what exactly it is you're trying to do, because the solution to your problem is very simple. I assume you're creating the list dynamically, in which case you already know if activity 111 was added before activity 121 and you can take an action based on that.

Anyway, I hope this helps.

Comment: this is great solution, removing double-quote was great and converting the list to string was something I didn't think of, still a beginner..I basically have a file with 3.5 million lines and the line that you added in myListOfDicts, is only 1 of those lines, I had to run through that huge file and get lines only where activity 121 existed, followed by subsequent activity 115/116 , which I could find taking clues from your code..thanks a ton

Comment: I also have another puzzle to solve, now I have 200,000 lines similar to one here: